# SQL Inner Join with unique entries based on the latest Timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT h.Id,h.Name,max(h.Stamp),u.email 
FROM schema.heating h 
inner JOIN  schema.users u ON h.unique_id = u.unique_id 
where u.email= 'example@example.com' 
group by h.Name
```

I am trying to make this statement return unique entries(name) for the latest timestamp based on an inner join with another table on unique_id,
however it is not returning the latest timestamp for each entry with max(Stamp),would anyone have any ideas where i am may be going wrong here ?
I have been trying this for a while now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could be you need  select where the tuple that  match the result fo your select

```
  select * 
  from schema.heating h 
  where (h.Name, h.Stamp) in  ( 
            SELECT h.Name, max(h.Stamp)
            FROM schema.heating h 
            inner JOIN  schema.users u ON h.unique_id = u.unique_id 
            where u.email= 'example@example.com' 
            group by h.Name )
```

Comment: Hi scaisEdge, first off thank you for the fast response ,I just tried this but it unfortuneately it didnt work in mysql anyway

Comment: I can get this to return the latest entry in one table by using ORDER BY Stamp DESC LIMIT 1; but i also need the other table join included. for some reason max(Stamp) will not work in the same way for me.

Comment: Subquery returns more than 1 row